# Java Assert same values but Erroring

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I'm working with two List and trying to use the contains().  I don't break the convention but still am getting false with my class usage for contains.

Items.class

```
 class Items implements Comparable<Items> {
     private String name;
     private Date date;
     private Lib.CLASSENUM type;

    public getDate();
    public setDate();

    ....
    public compareTo(Items o) {
     ...
    }
  }
```

Test.class

```
List<Items> actualList;
List<Items> expectedList;

public setup() {
     actualList = new ArrayList<>();
     expectedList = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Tests {
@Test
public void statusCheckValidatingRedLinePromotionItemsTest() {
    //this just sets the two ArrayList to clear
    clearProductMaps();
    Items goodsItem = new Items();

    goodsItem.setName("Product_A");
    goodsItem.setPrice(4.10);
    goodsItem.setStatus(Lib.CLASSENUM.ORIGINAL);
    goodsItem.setDate(date);

    actualList.add(goodsItem);
    goodsItem = new Items();
    goodsItem.settName("Product_A");
    goodsItem.setPrice(3.70);
    goodsItem.setStatus(Lib.CLASSENUM.PROMO);
    date = calendar.getTime();
    goodsItem.setDate(date);

    actualList.add(goodsItem);
    goodsItem = new Items();
    goodsItem.setName("Product_A");
    goodsItem.setPrice(3.70);
    goodsItem.setDate(date);
    goodsItem.setStatus(Lib.CLASSENUM.PROMO);
    expectedList.add(goodsItem);

    assertTrue(expectedGoods.get(0).contains(actualList.get(0));
}
```

The contains should be true, no?
(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get a matching item because `contains(..)` method of `ArrayList` relies on equality checking, rather than on `Compararble<T>` implementation.

Once you override and implement `equals(..)` and `hashCode()` in the `Item` class, the tests are going to pass.

Alternatively, you could use `TreeSet<T>`, which relies on `Compararble<T>`, in place of `ArrayList<T>` to check containment.

Answer (score 0):

One thing right off the bat that I notice is that you misspelled *Comparable*. Comparable as an interface deals with custom sorting, not equality checking, as dasblinkenlight has pointed out.

Comment: only in meeting a deadline of sorts so it wasn't a runtime or compiler error with the edit above when it was posted.